# some emacs bindings undefined on macOS

Tags: key-bindings, mac

For instance, for s-! (M-! on my linux machine, running a single shell command) it says it is undefined,
although s-x (M-x) works just fine
(It seems like on mac it calls it s and not M?)
Help am new to mac

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: why doesn't it work and how could i make it identify the binding as it should?

Comment: Where did you get Emacs, what version? What does `C-h w shell-command RET` say? Do you have the same problem if you run `emacs -Q`? if you run `emacs -q`?

Comment: Edit your question to make it a clear question. Only *one* question. (Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions and answers need to stand on their own.)